# Query not resulting correct records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT id, name FROM users
WHERE ((id = 1) OR (5 <= 5))
```

This should result all records as 5 = 5, but it's not. It's only resulting records where the id = 1.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
This is the full query:

```
SELECT project_id, project_name, project_description, project_active, 
            users.user_firstname, users.user_lastname FROM projects 
            INNER JOIN users ON projects.user_id = users.user_id 
            WHERE (projects.user_id = 1 || 3 <= 3)
```

EDIT:
Found it =/
Something was wrong with the join; user_id didn't exist anymore for some reason.

Comment: What happens if you remove all of the parenthesis?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that query, and if I setup a database of my own and use it I'll see all the rows in `users`. What does your table look like? What are some of the rows you expect to see but don't?

Comment: Then there's a serious problem with your mysql installation. Just tested here, and it load all results, as expected.

Comment: What happens if you remove the id = 1? Select * from users where 5 = 5?

Comment: I have updated the post with the full query. Removing parenthesis doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Andre: I get the same result :s

Comment: inner join is not going to bring all the results, only where there is a match in projects.user_id = users.user_id = 1. I think it's outer join to bring everything, but I'm not sure. Maybe you'll have to switch the sides of the join (right join)

Comment: The `INNER JOIN` is definitely a factor, since MySQL must first perform the join (which it can do only when there are matching rows) and THEN apply your `WHERE` clause. If you want to find all rows from `users` regardless of whether there are corresponding rows in `projects`, use a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT id, name FROM users where id=1 or 5<=5;

SHOW WARNINGS;
```

u will find mysql executes the query is:

```
SELECT id,name FROM users where 1
```

just means (id=1 or 5<=5) is same as 1

Answer (score 0):

So do you want all records smaller or equal 5?

if so its only

```
SELECT id, name FROM users
WHERE id <= 5
```

Beside that

```
(5 <= 5)
```

is "5" a table row like id?

Comment: Read that query a little more carefully. The original has `(5 <= 5)` which is a tautology. The question is: why, if it's a tautology, aren't all rows returned?

Comment: @VoteyDiscipleI had never see this before, may be others yes but value to value no, it that unique feature from MySQL or its from ISO SQL.

Comment: It's ANSI standard. You can compare anything you want to anything else you want, including two values. (It's not often useful, except in generated SQL statements, but the DBMS doesn't care how you got the values as long as it's got stuff to compare.)

Comment: @VoteyDisciple So what is the value pf comparing value to value in a query.

Comment: Most likely, the query is generated programmatically, and one of the two values originated in program-side data. Whether that's actually the best approach to writing a particular query is definitely debatable, but I've seen cases where it's by far the most efficient approach (in both processing time and in simplicity of application code).

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
$q = ("SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id = 1 || 5 <= 5");
```

This is how I do it.